# 'dict' object has no attribute 'id'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, xml, list

This is my code. I'm trying to translate xml string into python list to be shown in html template.

```
self.task_xml = "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <django-objects version="1.0">
<object model="task.task" pk="31">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="32">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">0</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="33">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
<object model="task.task" pk="34">
<field name="name" type="CharField">New Task</field>
<field name="parent_task_id" type="IntegerField">31</field>
</object>
</django-objects>"

 58         self.xmlData = ET.fromstring(self.db.task_xml)
 59 
 60         self.task_list = []
 61         taskList = []                                                           
 62         for obj in self.xmlData.iter("object"):
 63             parent_task_id = obj.find("field[@name='parent_task_id']").text
 64             if parent_task_id == EMPTY_UUID:
 65                 taskList.append({'id': obj.get("pk"),
 66                     'name': obj.find("field[@name='name']").text,
 67                     'parent_task_id': parent_task_id ,
 68                     })
 69         # Apprend taskList:
 70         for task in taskList:
 71             taskViewModel = TaskViewModel(task.id, True)
 72             self.task_list.append(taskViewModel)
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
'dict' object has no attribute 'id'
```

And it is task.id in line 71

Do you think I have a problem with this in line 65:

```
'id': obj.get("pk")
```

Comment: Instead of using `task.id` you should use `task['id']`

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You are accessing the dictionary wrongly. You need to use subscript with string `'id'` , Example -

```
taskViewModel = TaskViewModel(task['id'], True)
```

Comment: Is there any way I can add you or follow you in github, fb or anything?

Comment: I am not that active on github, though I do have an account, If you want - https://github.com/anandkr07

Answer (score 10):

I got the same error when accessing **"id"** in dictionary with **dot "."** like **JavaScript** as shown below because I also use **JavaScript** quite often in addition to **Python**:

```py
user = {"id": 1, "name": "John"}
print(user.id) # Error
```

So, I accessed **"id"** with **brackets "[]"** as shown below then the error was solved:

```py
user = {"id": 1, "name": "John"}
print(user["id"]) # 1
```